# Unable to loop through javascript object

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I have a object district_boundaries which is leaflet geojson object
`var district_boundary = new L.geoJson();`
and the data is added through ajax call to a geojson file of district

```
$.ajax({
dataType: "json",
url: "data/district.geojson",
success: function(data) {
    $(data.features).each(function(key, data) {
        district_boundary.addData(data);
        district_boundary.setStyle(district_boundary_styles["default"]);

    });
}
```

});

[image]
So in the _layers there are 75 values, one example of such values is the one in the picture with key 149.
I need to loop through all these 75 values and get the values from *features* key. i.e the name of districts and use them to label the districts.
I tried with this

```
_test = district_boundary._layers;
for (var aht in _test) {
   console.log('inside the loop');
   var b = _test[aht];
   console.log(b.feature.properties.NAME_3);
}
```

This works fine when tried in the console and shows the result 
[image]
But when i tried with by running in the script of my page this doesnot work the though _test  is populated with the values in district_boundary._layers, **loop is not executed**. What could be the reason can anyone please help me with this?

the output of msg and msg.d is 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Everything in the code is fine except the flow of execution. I was trying to use the data which would be defined later according to the flow, so in the part of script where i tried to loop through _test it is not populated yet, but when i tried in console it was after all the data was loaded and hence it worked.

Comment: I just did the same exact thing :)

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing your JSON data is getting wrapped in a `d` variable. Try the following -

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "data/district.geojson",
    success: function(msg) {
        //console.log(msg); //try this to see whether the data is really getting wrapped in d
        var data = msg.d; //msg.d contains the actual data
        $(data.features).each(function(key, data) {
            district_boundary.addData(data);
            district_boundary.setStyle(district_boundary_styles["default"]);        
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: no the data is in `msg` not in `msg.d`. Cannot read property 'features' of undefined. I just figured out the problem is with flow of execution of my code. thanks anyways

Comment: can you add the output of `console.log(msg)` to your question?